# Using --whole-archive in CMake on a library you build

Tags: build, cmake, ld, build-dependencies

I have a CMake project while builds a static library and links it with other code into an executable. For reasons I won't go into, I want this linking to happen with the `--whole-archive` linker flag.

Now, this flag is tricky, since you can't just add it anywhere - you have to toggle it, then list the libraries for which you want it to apply, then untoggle it.

I've read somewhere (the URL escapes me) that if you have a pre-existing library, you can effectively add this linker flags by doing the following:

```
# Just an example, find_library calls should really be isolated to separate find modules
find_library(FOO_LIBRARY foo)
set(FOO_LIBRARY "-Wl,--whole-archive ${FOO_LIBRARY} -Wl,--no-whole-archive")

add_executable(hello main.c)
target_link_libraries(hello ${FOO_LIBRARY})
```

and that's fine. But what if it's a static library that *you* are building for which you don't have a pre-existing variable (i.e. something for which you have an `add_library()` CMake command)? Do you have to manually indicate its path instead of ${FOO_LIBRARY}? Or is there some other trick you can use to obtain the path CMake would put on the command-line for it?

Also, if I were to use some kind of `${FOO_LIBRARY}`-like string instead of my static library target identifier - I believe CMake might miss the dependency, i.e. it might not re-link with the modified library (or not even build it) because the target_link_libraries command will see a strange string rather than the identifier of another target.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using:

```
add_dependencies(the_exe the_static_lib)
set_target_properties(the_exe LINK_FLAGS
    "-L/path/to/the_static_lib -Wl,--whole-archive,-lthe_static_lib,--no-whole-archive")
```

The value of `-L/path/to/the_static_lib` follows transparently from what you specify the output directory of
the target to be, or the default output directory of the target if you don't. E.g. if `the_static_lib` is
just output in the build directory, then `-L/path/to/the_static_lib` would be `-L.`

Here is a project to illustrate in a reasonably general way, where we
have structured subdirectories for sources and headers and distinct conventional
output directories, `bin`, `lib`

```
$ ls -R
.:
app  build  CMakeLists.txt  foobar  inc

./app:
main.c

./build:

./foobar:
bar.c  foo.c

./inc:
foobar.h
```

With files:

**app/main.c**

```
#include <foobar.h>

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

**foobar/foo.c**

```
#include <foobar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**foobar/bar.c**

```
#include <foobar.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void bar(void)
{
    puts(__func__);
}
```

**inc/foobar.h**

```
#ifndef FOOBAR_H
#define FOOBAR_H

void foo(void);
void bar(void);

#endif
```

**CMakeLists.txt (1)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(app)
include_directories(inc)
add_library(foobar STATIC foobar/foo.c foobar/bar.c)
set_target_properties(foobar
    PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
add_executable(app app/main.c)
add_dependencies(app foobar)
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
    LINK_FLAGS "-Llib -Wl,--whole-archive,-lfoobar,--no-whole-archive")
```

We want to make `./build/lib/libfoobar.a` from `./foobar/foo.c` and `./foobar/bar.c`.
And we want to make `./build/bin/app` from `./app/main.c`, linking the whole archive `./build/lib/libfoobar.a`

Generate, build and run:

```
$ cd build; cmake ..; make; ./bin/app
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build
Scanning dependencies of target foobar
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/foobar/foo.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/foobar/bar.c.o
[ 60%] Linking C static library lib/libfoobar.a
[ 60%] Built target foobar
Scanning dependencies of target app
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/app.dir/app/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable bin/app
[100%] Built target app
foo
bar
```

Similarly if, e.g. instead of that `CMakeLists.txt` we have:

**CMakeLists.txt (2)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(app)
include_directories(inc)
add_subdirectory(foobar)
add_executable(app app/main.c)
add_dependencies(app foobar)
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
    LINK_FLAGS "-Llib -Wl,--whole-archive,-lfoobar,--no-whole-archive")
```

and separately:

**foobar/CMakeLists.txt (1)**

```
add_library(foobar STATIC foo.c bar.c)
set_target_properties(foobar
    PROPERTIES ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/lib")
```

And with the same separation, but default output directories, we'd have:

**CMakeLists.txt (3)**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(app)
include_directories(inc)
add_subdirectory(foobar)
add_executable(app app/main.c)
add_dependencies(app foobar)
set_target_properties(app PROPERTIES
    LINK_FLAGS "-Lfoobar -Wl,--whole-archive,-lfoobar,--no-whole-archive")
```

**foobar/CMakeLists.txt (2)**

```
add_library(foobar STATIC foo.c bar.c)
```

which would go like:

```
$ cd build; cmake ..; make; ./app
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/imk/develop/so/cmake_prob/build
Scanning dependencies of target foobar
[ 20%] Building C object foobar/CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/foo.c.o
[ 40%] Building C object foobar/CMakeFiles/foobar.dir/bar.c.o
[ 60%] Linking C static library libfoobar.a
[ 60%] Built target foobar
Scanning dependencies of target app
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/app.dir/app/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable app
[100%] Built target app
foo
bar
```

Comment: It's kind of hacky, but, well, it seems like it works.

Comment: This does not work 100% `add_dependencies(app foobar)` says, build `app` after `foobar`. But not: if `foobar` needs to rebuild, `app` also needs to rebuild! See [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html). Its better to also add `target_link_libraries(app foobar)`, even if this link nothing or only parts.