# TEST_P tests in library do not run when INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P is called in a separate executable

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest

I'm trying to follow the instructions for [Creating Value-Parameterized Abstract Tests](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#creating-value-parameterized-abstract-tests) in the googletest README. I've created a project directory, in which I have `CMakeLists.txt`, `fixture.hh`, `fixture.cc`, `test.cc`, and the entire Google Test repository checked out within subdirectory `googletest`. My goal is simply to create a library with a text fixture class and a set of `TEST_P` tests that can be linked against by individual unit test executables to minimize code duplication.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(googletest)
include(GoogleTest)

add_library(test_utils STATIC fixture.cc)
target_link_libraries(test_utils PUBLIC gtest)

add_executable(unit_tests test.cc)
target_link_libraries(unit_tests PRIVATE test_utils gtest_main)
gtest_discover_tests(unit_tests)
```

```
// fixture.hh

#pragma once

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace test_utils { /* *************************************************** */

class Fixture : public ::testing::TestWithParam<size_t> {};

} /* namespace test_utils *************************************************** */
```

```
// fixture.cc

#include "fixture.hh"

using namespace test_utils;

TEST_P( Fixture, foo )
{
  ASSERT_EQ( GetParam()%2, 0 );
}
```

```
// test.cc

#include "fixture.hh"

namespace { /* ************************************************************** */

using namespace test_utils;

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P( BarInstantiation, Fixture, ::testing::Values( 18 ) );

} /* namespace ************************************************************** */
```

When I run `./unit_tests`, it outputs:

```
Running main() from ../googletest/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

`ctest` outputs `No tests were found!!!`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

As you know, the standard procedure for unit-testing with googletest is:

1. Build a library containing the code-under-test.
2. Write your googletest unit-tests in one or more source files.
3. Optionally, write a source file that defines `main` in [the standard googletest manner](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/primer.md#writing-the-main-function)
   to run the unit-tests. Alternatively, you may not define any `main` but instead add `libgtest_main` to your linkage.
4. Compile all the googletest sources from **2** and **3** to object files.
5. Link a googletest test-runner, inputting all object files together with the library from **1** plus `libgtest_main` (if you need it), plus `libgtest`

You would like to link `libgtest_main` instead of defining `main`, *and* you would like to
vary the procedure in an unorthodox way by archiving all the object files from **2** in a static library and adding it to your linkage
instead of linking the object files directly.

And in your posted example, there's a further trivial variation. You haven't got any library
of code-under-test, because it's not needed to illustrate your problem. You've just got a place-holder
unit-test that is bound to pass, if it gets run. The problem being that it doesn't even get run!

Let's put CMake aside for the moment as it's an irrelevant distraction for
explaining your puzzle. Here I have your files as posted:

```
$ ls -R
.:
fixture.cc  fixture.hh  test.cc
```

First I'm going to build a googletest runner by the standard procedure (except for the
fact that there's no code-under-test).

Compile the sources:

```
$ g++ -Wall -Wextra -c test.cc fixture.cc
```

Link:

```
$ g++ -o tester test.o fixture.o -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
```

Run:

```
$ ./tester
Running main() from /home/imk/Downloads/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from BarInstantiation/Fixture
[ RUN      ] BarInstantiation/Fixture.foo/0
[       OK ] BarInstantiation/Fixture.foo/0 (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from BarInstantiation/Fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

Nothing wrong with that.

Now I'll make the test runner again the way you want to. No need to recompile
any sources. I'll just make a static library contaning `fixture.o`:

```
$ ar rcs libutest.a fixture.o
```

And relink using it instead of `fixture.o`:

```
$ g++ -o tester test.o -L. -lutest -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
```

And again run:

```
$ ./tester
Running main() from /home/imk/Downloads/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

There's your puzzle. There are no tests now. How come?

Finally I'm going to link the test runner a third way:

```
$ g++ -o tester test.o -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
```

Not linking *either* `fixture.o` or `libutest.a`. And that one runs:

```
$ ./tester
Running main() from /home/imk/Downloads/googletest-master/googletest/src/gtest_main.cc
[==========] Running 0 tests from 0 test cases.
[==========] 0 tests from 0 test cases ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 0 tests.
```

exactly like the second one. In this case that's not surprising. We *know* that
a googletest runner can be linked without any tests, and that's what it will do.

Let's do some study of the symbols that are defined in `fixture.o`.

```
$ nm -C --defined-only fixture.o | egrep -w '(W|V)' | wc -l
463
```

There 463  [*weak* symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_symbol) defined. And there are just 2
strong symbols defined, which are:

```
$ nm -C --defined-only fixture.o | egrep -w '(A|B|C|D|G|R|S|T)'
0000000000000000 B Fixture_foo_Test::gtest_registering_dummy_
0000000000000000 T Fixture_foo_Test::TestBody()
```

The linker distinguishes importantly between *weak* and *strong* symbols.

The linker will not link a program that contains any strong symbol reference that it fails
to resolve, i.e. for which it can find no definition in the linkage. It will fail
the linkage with *undefined reference* errors. But it does not have to resolve
*weak* references to link a program. An unresolved reference to a weak symbol simply remains null ( = 0) in the program.

The linker will not link a program (or shared library) whose linkage produces
multiple strong definitions of the same symbol. It will fail the linkage with
*multiple definition* errors. But it will tolerate multiple *weak* definitions
as well as one strong definition of the same symbol, in which case it picks
the strong definition to resolve references and discards all the weak ones. And it
will tolerate multiple weak definitions of a symbol without any strong one. In
that case it will pick one of the weak definitions arbitrarily - in practice,
just the first one that it sees - and discards all the rest.

A C++ compiler routinely emits mixtures of weak and strong symbol definitions
in order to translate C++ into successfully linkable object code. Inline class methods
and instantiations of function templates have to be compiled with weak definitions.

The linker's different obligations to weak references and strong references
are connected with its different obligations to an input file that is *object file*
and one that is a *static library*.

When you offer an object file `foo.o` to the linker, it will link it into the program *unconditionally*.

A [static library](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/static-libraries/info) is an archive of object files that you offer to the linker *from
which to extract just the ones it needs*, and link *them* into the program. By default it won't
extract and link any of them unconditionally. Only the ones that resolve
symbols already referred to in the linkage *for which it needs to find definitions*.

But a *weak* symbol reference is one that the linker *does not need to resolve*
to link a program. So by default it will *never* extract and link an object file from a static
library to resolve a *weak* symbol reference. The reference is allowed to be undefined
in the program, so the linker will expend no effort searching libraries to define it.

Putting together the facts we've just reviewed, we know that the linkage:

```
$ g++ -o tester test.o fixture.o -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
```

which executed the `TEST_P` defined in `fixture.cc`, is one that *will* link `fixture.o` into the program, because it is an object file.

And we also know that the linkage:

```
$ g++ -o tester test.o -L. -lutest -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
```

which executed 0 tests, will extract and link `libutest.a(fixture.o)` into
the program *only* if `test.o` contains at least one reference to
a strong symbol that is defined in `fixture.o`, i.e. a reference to one of:

```
Fixture_foo_Test::gtest_registering_dummy_
Fixture_foo_Test::TestBody()
```

since all the 463 other symbols defined in `fixture.o` are weak.

But `test.o` makes no references to any symbols containing `Fixture_foo_Test`:

```
$ nm -C test.o | grep Fixture_foo_Test; echo Done
Done
```

So we can conclude that the linkage:

```
$ g++ -o tester test.o -L. -lutest -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
```

will *not* extract and link `libutest.a(fixture.o)`. It is exactly the same
linkage as:

```
$ g++ -o tester test.o -lgtest_main -lgtest -pthread
```

which as we know contains 0 tests.

Putting `fixture.o` into a static library renders it *unnecessary* to the linkage
of `tester`, and it isn't linked.

In that light of all that, your CMakeLists.txt is easy to fix by simplifying it to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10 FATAL_ERROR)

enable_testing()
add_subdirectory(googletest)
include(GoogleTest)

add_executable(unit_tests test.cc fixture.cc)
target_link_libraries(unit_tests PRIVATE gtest_main gtest)
gtest_discover_tests(unit_tests)
```

which will result in `fixture.o` being unconditionally linked into `unit_tests`
and the program will output:

```
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test suite.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from BarInstantiation/Fixture
[ RUN      ] BarInstantiation/Fixture.foo/0
[       OK ] BarInstantiation/Fixture.foo/0 (0 ms)
[----------] 1 test from BarInstantiation/Fixture (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test suite ran. (0 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

as you hoped.

Clearly this solution doesn't satisfy your stated motivation for creating `libtest_utils.a`
in the first place:

> My goal is simply to create a library with a text fixture class and a set of TEST_P tests that can be linked against by individual unit test executables to minimize code duplication.

But that goal is misconceived. There is no point in building a *static library* from a set of `TEST_P` test sources (or any sources) if you are going to *rebuild it from the same sources*
for linkage with each executable that needs some of the object files you will archive in the static library. If you were going to rebuild it from source for each executable that needs it,
you would minimize code duplication just by keeping all the `TEST_P` test sources in one shared place or repository, and there would *still* be no point in rebuilding the static library
for each executable. Each of those executable projects might just as well include some or all of the library's `TEST_P` sources among it's *own* sources and not bother rebuilding the library or linking
against it.

On the other hand, you would have a *code reuse* motivation for building a static library from `TEST_P` test sources if you intended *not* to rebuild it for every
unit-test executable project, but to build it as an independent project and simply consume it in the linkage of unit-test executables that you build later. You
don't want to do *that* however, for the same good reasons that googletest itself [is best built within each unit-test project that uses it](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md#incorporating-into-an-existing-cmake-project),
just as you are doing. It defeats the purpose of building googletest as an in-project dependency if you then link the
executable with a library of object files that were compiled sometime in the past in a different project with a possibly different googletest revision, possibly with a different compiler.

You want googletest to be built by your unit-test project, and your `TEST_P` sources to be compiled and linked *with that same googletest*, in the same project. So there is
no point in archiving the `TEST_P` object files that you build into intermediate static library, as opposed to simply linking them directly in the unit-test executable. And,
if you *do* put them in an intermediate static library, by default the linker will ignore them.

I said *by default* the linker will ignore them, because it possible to force the linker to link an object
file from within a static library even if it doesn't need to. You can do that by forcing it to
extract and link *all* the object files in the static library, using the linker's [`--whole-archive` option](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html).
If invoking the linker as usual via gcc/g++ (or clang/clang++), the linkage options you'd need to do this for
a static library `libbar.a` would be:

```
... -Wl,--whole-archive -lbar -Wl,--no-whole-archive ...
```

You need to enable `--whole-archive` before `-lbar` and disable it afterwards because
otherwise it will apply not only to `-lbar` but to all subsequent libraries, including even
the the ones that you don't even mention in your commandline that are linked by default.

If you force the linkage of all object files in `libbar.a` like that, then of course
any weak definitions that they contain *will* be used to resolve weak symbol references
in the program.

However, it is not straightforward to achieve the linkage options `-Wl,--whole-archive -lbar -Wl,--no-whole-archive`
in a CMake project that builds `libbar.a`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43437424/1362568)
and answer. And once again, there is no point in it, so why fight the framework? Googletest expects you to build your unit-tests in your
unit-test project and do the obvious thing: link the object files with the program. If you do that,
your unit-tests will be linked and run as you expect.

Comment: Thank you so much for this incredibly elaborate explanation! Truly grateful. I'm a bit confused about a couple of things. I can't seem to find the actual use of weak linkage within the googletest source (perhaps there are variations of the syntax that I don't know to look for). It looks like `TEST_P` creates a class that it (hand waving here) adds to a registry, and `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` iterates through that registry to find individual tests. Surely the registry itself isn't weak? What symbols are actually weak?

Answer (score 2):

TEST_P is a macro which, when expanded, declares a full c++ class, onto which INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P adds functionality.

Since your TEST_P is in a separate .cc file, your INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P call (which is in its own .cc file) can't see it, so it's essentially defining a function with no owning class.

On the flip side, the class defined by TEST_P doesn’t get equipped with the method(s) INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P would have defined for it. So it doesn’t find any test instantiations to run.

You need to move your TEST_P declaration to where your INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P call can see it for it to work.

A caveat, though - TEST_P not only declares a class but defines several functions. So if you try to place it in a header file, you might receive some linker errors pertaining to these class methods (as already defined, for example). So the best place for it just might be right next to the INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P call.

TEST_P is really meant to be its own independent test case, and it seems like it was designed to go into its own source file, and not accessible as a sort of library component, as it seems you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi @qdin, thanks for the response. I'm a little skeptical. Here's a quote from the docs section that I linked: "You can instantiate the same abstract test suite multiple times, possibly in different source files." Sure enough, if I place `TEST_P` and `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` in separate source files and link them directly (no static library), I get the behavior one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check if it makes a difference if you link `fixture.cc` directly (without creating a static library first).

There is a test case in the official [googletest repository](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/0599a7b8410dc5cfdb477900b280475ae775d7f9/googletest/test/googletest-test2_test.cc#L49) that explicitly tests that test cases can be defined and instantiated in different translation units. I am not entirely sure, but adding a static library around `fixture.cc` it might lead to a [static initialization ordering problem](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order).

Comment: This does in fact succeed. If static initialization ordering is the problem, I would love to find out exactly how so.

Answer (score 1):

Going off of the description by Mike Kinghan, you can use CMake [Object Libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#object-libraries) since CMake 3.12:

```cmake
add_library(test_utils OBJECT fixture.cc)
```

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this issue in our project. Based on discussion within [Mike Kinghan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55044036/8050974), You can try below solution if you want to use a static library contained the test body.

First, defining a function in your test class to generate the test case name as below codes showing.

```
// fixture.hh

#pragma once

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace test_utils { /* *************************************************** */

class Fixture : public ::testing::TestWithParam<size_t> {

public:
       public:
       static std::string getTestCaseName(testing::TestParamInfo<size_t> obj){
            std::ostringstream name;
            name << "my_test_case_name_with_parameter_" << obj;
            return name.str();
       }
 
};

} /* namespace test_utils *************************************************** */
```

And then, use this function `getTestCaseName()` in `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` as the last inputting parameter.

```
// test.cc

#include "fixture.hh"

namespace { /* ************************************************************** */

using namespace test_utils;

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P( BarInstantiation, 
                         Fixture, 
                         ::testing::Values( 18 )，
                         Fixture::getTestCaseName);

} /* namespace ************************************************************** */
```

Finally rebuild your project and will get the expected result.